# Tableau - Adding dimensions together to show overall revenue

Tags: sum, tableau-api, dimensions, revenue

I am very new to Tableau (first day user) and have been a long time Excel user. I am trying to fully understand the power of Tableau to eventually move away from Excel.

I have a question concerning dimensions and creating a calculated field.

My table has multiple categories and sub-categories. My goal is to display the total revenue and average order value per chosen sub-category (this seems easy enough).

I want to then take those sub-categories and show a combined sum of revenue and average of the average order value. I am stuck on trying to also combine these sub-categories to show a blended view.

Furthermore, the 2 sub-categories are weighted very differently. The average order value of 1 has a much heavier weight than the other and will definitely affect the AOV when combined. How do you also assign a weight to this combined total?

Any help will be much appreciated. I know this may be a rather simple solution but I am new to the program and am having difficulty finding this answer.

Tableau screen:

[image: img1]

or

[img1 http://postimg.org/image/dq5wqgnyl/](http://postimg.org/image/dq5wqgnyl/)
Best, 
CR

Answer (score 0):

Put sub categories in the rows column.

Put sum revenue in the text pill in the marks section

In the analysis tab on the top select column grand totals.

I'm unable to see your images,i hope this answers a apart of your question.